# Error could not find driver en php 7.2

Tags: php

#### PHP:

```
<?php
//incluimos nuestra conexion
include_once("../Modelo/conexion_login.php");


try {
             //creamos nuestra conexion
             $dbConn = new PDO('mysqli:host=localhost; login_tm', 'root', '1998');

             $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // creamos el try catch para que nos diga lo que sucede con la conexion 
             


         $busqueda=$_GET["Buscar"];

         require ("../Modelo/conexion_login.php");

          $dbConn->exec("set_character set utf8");

          $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE CORREO LIKE '%$busqueda'";

          $result=$dbConn->prepare($sql);

          $result->execute(array("$busqueda"));
?>
```

---

#### HTML:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Ver Usuarios Registrados</title>
                <link rel="icon" type="/image/png" href="../../Login/img/tm.ico"/>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
                        <style>
                            .borde{
                                background-color: yellow;
                                text-align: left;
                            }
                             .borde2{
                                background-color: #0F8886;
                                height: 80px;
                                top: 620px;
                                
                            }
                               .borde3{
                                right: 24px;
                                
                            }
                            

                         
                        </style>

</head>

<body>
               <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-info navbar-dark"><!--navbar-expand-lg,md,fixed-bottom-->
                   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="ets2_00005.png" style="width: 30px;"></a>
                   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#uno">
                       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="uno"><!-- flex-center, flex-column nav-pills -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <h1>Administracion de usuarios</h1>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="../Vista/panel_de_control.php" class="nav-link">Volver al incio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbardrop">Link5</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub item 1</a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub item 2</a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub item 3</a>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Sub item 4</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <form action="busqueda.php" method="get" class="form-inline">
            <button class="btn-success" type="Submit" name="Buscar">Buscar</button>
        </form>
                        </ul>      
                    </div>       
            </nav>
  
    <br></br><br></br> 
    <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-dark table-hover" width='80%' border=0>
            
            

    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Correo</td>
        <td>Contraseña</td>
        <td>Tipo Usuario</td>
                <td>Editar Usuario</td>
                <td>Eliminar Usuario</td>
        
    </tr>
    <?php     
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['correo']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['contrasena']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['tipo_usuario']."</td>";    
        echo "<td><a href=\"../Controlador/editar_usuarios.php?id=$row[id]\">Editar</a</td>";
                 echo "<td><a href=\"../Controlador/eliminar_usuario.php?id=$row[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Eliminar</a></td>";        
    }

         }catch(PDOException $e) {
             die('Error ' . $e->getMessage());
         }finally{
             $dbConn=null;
         }
    ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="borde3">

    </div>
    <div>
               <h1 class="col-12 borde2 fixed-bottom display-4"></h1>  
               
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: en tu cadena de conexión pones mysqli, cuando solo es mysql; mysqli es otra forma de conexión; las estas confundiendo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Si quieres que tu pregunta tenga una buena acogida debes empezar describiendo el problema que tienes, lo que quieres hacer, lo que te sale ahora, el error que tienes, etc. No puedes lanzar un código sin más donde nadie sabe siquiera lo que hace tu programa, nadie se animará a leer un código completo tratando de adivinar lo que hace o donde falla. Sería mejor que tú lo expongas ¿no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te comento que tu error se encuentra en la línea siguiente

```
$dbConn = new PDO('mysqli:host=localhost; login_tm', 'root', '1998');
```

¿por qué?

Bien PDO es una capa de abstracción para poder interactuar con varios gestgores de bases de datos, entre los cuales por supuesto esta MySQL; sin embargo cuando creas la conexión debes apuntar al driver MySQL y tu por el contrario colocas mysqli el cual por supuesto no reconoce por que no existe

solución

Declara tu misma cadena de conexión pero apuntando a mysql

```
$dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname = login_tm', 'root', '1998');
```

> Por otro lado también es necesario que coloques dbname = nombre_bd
>   para indicar a que base de datos deseas acceder

Aqui mas información de la documentación oficial de PDO que es para PHP

http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Comment: muchas,gracias por ayudar a este novato, me funciono saludos .

Comment: una gran aporte @AlfredoGomiz